# Confirmation about an Oracle tutorial typo

Tags: java, oracle, io, nio

Do they mean checked exception with "exception exceptions" right?

Quoting from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html) oracle java tutorial:

> Note that if there is an exception during directory iteration then
>   DirectoryIteratorException is thrown with the IOException as the
>   cause. Iterator methods cannot throw exception exceptions.

Comment: Just for curiosity from a peek at your past questions : Are you hunting for errors in the Oracle tutorials?

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 Yes my friends call me the oracle bugs hunter. ;P not really it's just I am preparing for the OCPJP7 and every detail is precious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be correct; since the methods defined on `Iterator` do not throw any checked exceptions, iterator implementations can't either. File that bug report!

Comment: where to report such bugs? I tried to find proper place on "contact us" site, but it's really pain and I didn't succeed.